# Sphinx __main__ and inner functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

So I was wondering what it would take to get Sphinx to auto gen some documentation in my __main__.py, so far I just can't seem to make it work. I've got some other python files that will auto gen some stuff just fine.

inside __main__.py

```
import os

def main():
    """
    Some helpful stuff about main
    """

    def function_1(stuff):
        """
        Some helpful stuff about function_1
        """
        pass

    def function_2(things):
        """
        Some helpful stuff about function_2
        """
        pass

    print(function_1())
    print(function_2())
    do_the_other_code_dot_jpg()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Inside of index.rst

```
Welcome to Some Test Docs
=========================

This is some test text.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   code


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

inside of code.rst

```
Report
======

.. automodule:: __main__
  :members:
```

A tree of current directory structure

```
Sphinx/
├── doc
│   ├── _build
│   │   ├── doctrees
│   │   │   ├── code.doctree
│   │   │   ├── environment.pickle
│   │   │   └── index.doctree
│   │   └── html
│   │       ├── code.html
│   │       ├── genindex.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── objects.inv
│   │       ├── py-modindex.html
│   │       ├── search.html
│   │       ├── searchindex.js
│   │       ├── _sources
│   │       │   ├── code.rst.txt
│   │       │   └── index.rst.txt
│   │       └── _static
│   │           ├── ajax-loader.gif
│   │           ├── alabaster.css
│   │           ├── basic.css
│   │           ├── comment-bright.png
│   │           ├── comment-close.png
│   │           ├── comment.png
│   │           ├── custom.css
│   │           ├── doctools.js
│   │           ├── down.png
│   │           ├── down-pressed.png
│   │           ├── file.png
│   │           ├── jquery-3.1.0.js
│   │           ├── jquery.js
│   │           ├── minus.png
│   │           ├── plus.png
│   │           ├── pygments.css
│   │           ├── searchtools.js
│   │           ├── underscore-1.3.1.js
│   │           ├── underscore.js
│   │           ├── up.png
│   │           ├── up-pressed.png
│   │           └── websupport.js
│   ├── code.rst
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _static
│   └── _templates
└── __main__.py
```

[Here is an image of the index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiydo.png)

[Here is an image of the __main__ module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXAb5.png)

Comment: I edited the post to include a tree of the current directory structure and added some pictures. If I change the name of \_\_main\_\_.py to something else, e.g. "normalname.py" and change that in code.rst I get the desired result.. (I tried posting a picture of the desired result but I'm only allowed two links, if needed I'll make an imgur album for the results picture)

Comment: Did you [enable the Sphinx extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-extensions) known as [sphinx.ext.autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) either in your `conf.py` or via command line? Are there any error or warning messages? Also you can use [sphinx-apidoc to generate the `.rst` shell for you automatically](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html).

Comment: Making a top-level module named `__main__` seems like a really, really bad idea. It will conflict with the automatically named `__main__` module that holds the script being run.

Comment: Sphinx itself has a module called `sphinx.__main__` (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/__main__.py). From the image of the `__main__` module output, it can be seen that you are getting the documentation from that module.